Copy paste from Excel to HTML
(I'm not that good at English so I used Google Translate.)
I have an Excel sheet with data in A1, B1, etc. A text is formed from several parts in the Excel sheet:
="● from "&TEXT(DATE(MIDDLE(A40; 7; 4); MID(A40; 4; 2); LEFT(A40; 2));" Dddd ")&"the"&TEXT(DATE(MIDDLE(A40; 7; 4); MID(A40; 4; 2); LEFT(A40; 2));" D. MMMM YYYY") & "to "& TEXT(DATE(MIDDLE(B40; 7; 4); MID(B40; 4; 2); LEFT(B40; 2));" Dddd ")&"the"&TEXT(DATE(MIDDLE(B40; 7; 4); MID(B40; 4; 2); LEFT(B40; 2));" D. MMMM YYYY") &" have you worked "&MID(I16; 1; FIND(":"; I16)-1)&" hours and "&MID(I16; FIND(":"; I16)+1; LENGTH(I16))&" minutes" & "and took leave in "&MIDT(K16; 1; FIND(":"; K16)-1)&" hours and "&MID(K16; FIND(":"; K16)+1; LENGTH(K16))& "minutes"

When I copy the rows in Excel and put them in an HTML-based subject system, the text is inserted without line breaks.
If I insert the same rows from the same sheet with Power Automate, line breaks are set. I only use Power Automate if there are more than 10 lines, as I can't get Power Automate to place the text correctly in the course system, so it's faster to make line breaks than to correct the text. I have tried with char (10) and much more without success. If anyone can help I will be very happy.

Please, format properly your question.

If it's HTML then <br> might add a line break, depending on what the software you're pasting it in to allows.

the ="● from is only to show that a new period is started. Can you help how put  into the end off the formala in excel?

@Mefa & "<br>" should do it.

As others mentioned, <BR> is the line break, but if you want to see the code break, you can do char(13) or even combine char(10) & char(13).
char(13) is carriage return 
char(10) is line feed
